# Spring data jpa mssql driverClassName error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to connect to MSSQL but I am getting the error:

**ERROR**

> driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:  Could not load JDBC driver class
>   [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]

**CONFIG**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.100:55209;databaseName=SampleSpring?autoReconnect=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;" />
        <property name="username" value="nmcadmin" />
        <property name="password" value="s3Cr3t@cct" />
    </bean>
```

**DIALECT**

```
<entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
```

**POM.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
   <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It throws error when I post this dependency in pom.xml
How to solve this?

Comment: ERROR driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]

Comment: CONFIG - <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />

Comment: <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />

Comment: When i do it with my-sql it working perfectly....?

Comment: Are you using a persistence.xml where another driver is still defined?

Comment: @dean try giving as below `<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerD‌​river</property>`

Comment: @ankur-singhal the above is not working its throws an error when I give the above tag in my context xml.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found 
Download maven

Download sqljdbc from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774

Run sqljdbc__enu.exe
Enter an install directory when prompted; it is recommended that you unpack
   this zip file in %ProgramFiles% with the default directory.

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0

Then update your project and run your project